# How to change axis value labels orientation?

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, excel-2007

I have a chart in Excel; I need to change orientation of text labels in one of the axis programmatically. Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will change the orientation of the X-axis tick labels.

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = 45 ' degrees
```

This is how to change the orientation of the axis title:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Orientation = 81 ' degrees
```

Have you ever tried recording macros? If not, you should! Looking at the resulting code is a great way to quickly learn this type of thing.

Comment: 1. I tried recording macro, and there wasn't such code there. 2. It doesn't compile, as this field accepts XlTickLabelOrientation enum only.

Comment: It compiles and works fine on Excel 2003. What version are you using? This code is produced when recording the followingy: right-click the axis, Format Axis, Alignment, set the Orientation. What code shows up in your recorded macro?

Comment: I use Excel 2007. Macro recorder shows only ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select and nothing after.

Comment: Well, that's weird... it's not actually recording anything?! I don't have Excel 2007, so I can't reproduce your situation, unfortunately.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett, I've found this is a known issue and macro recorder in Office2007 is a bit broken. It seems using your code and force casting my angle number to XlTickLabelOrientation makes it working, but that's really weird.

Comment: Interesting. You should post your code as an answer so that others can benefit from your experience.

Comment: In Excel 2010 macro recorder also fails on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Layout tab (which appears when you have a chart selected) -> labels -> axis titles.

or

Right click the chart axis -> format axis -> Alignment

or

VBA solution as Jean-François Corbett pointed out